# Quadratic Variation Mixed Process Poisson and Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, quadratic-variation

I am trying to solve this problem where we're asked to compute the quadratic variation of a process.
I assume that it is necessary to apply Ito's formula but not sure how to get the right solution.
Furthermore, I'm also not sure about how to apply Ito's formula to a function that includes integrals like this one. I am familiar with the basic Ito Formula and know how to apply it to simpler functions.

Let N be a (P,F)-Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$ > 0 and define the process:
X = $(X)_t$

$$ X_t =  2 + \int_{0}^{t} \sqrt{s} dW_s + N_t $$

Compute $[X]_t$

is this attempt correct?

$$ X_t =  2 + \int_{0}^{t} \sqrt{s} dW_s + N_t $$

which we can write in differential form as:

$$ dX_t =   \sqrt{t}dW_t + dN_t $$

then the quadratic variation is given as:

$$ d[X_t] =  dX_t * dX_t = (\sqrt{t}dW_t + dN_t) * (\sqrt{t}dW_t + dN_t) = tdt + dNt  $$

which we can then write again in integral form to get $[X_t]$

$$ [X_t] =  \int_{0}^{t} t dt + \int_{0}^{t} dN_t = \frac{t^2}{2} + N_t  $$

If this attempt is correct, I am not quite sure why $dN_t * dN_t = dN_t$  would be true in the quadratic covariation step. I assumed that the cross terms cancel out.

Comment: Do you know what is quadratic variation of $N_t$?

Comment: I believe it is $N_t$ itself but i'm not totally sure why

Comment: Right. You can try proving that by noting that Poisson process is a constant except for the jumps, the places where it jumps you get a one. Calculating quadratic variation is then just summing up the number of jumps.

Comment: Now, the next question is what is the quadratic covariation of Brownian motion with Poisson process. Once again the idea is that that since Poisson process is constant most of the time, the quadratic covariation gets killed (in this case, note that you don’t sum 1 but the increment of Brownian motion).

Comment: so $[W_s, N_t]$ is zero then?
I think i remember reading that the covariation is defined as:

$[\int H dM, N] = \int H d[M,N] $  where M,N are local martingales and H is a square integrable Martingale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a sequence of partitions $0=t^n_0<\dots< t^n_n=t$ and $\Pi_n:=\max\limits_{i=1,\dots, n}|t^n_i-t^n_{i-1}|$ we have by definition
\begin{align}
[W,N]_t&=\lim_{\scriptstyle n\to\infty\atop\scriptstyle\Pi_n\to\, 0}\sum_{i=1}^n\Big(W_{t^n_i}-W_{t^n_{i-1}}\Big)\Big(N_{t^n_i}-N_{t^n_{i-1}}\Big)\,.
\end{align}
Since $N_t$ is increasing and $W_t$ is continuous (therefore uniformly continuous on $[0,t]$),
\begin{align}
\Big|[W,N]_t\Big|&\le\lim_{\scriptstyle n\to\infty\atop\scriptstyle\Pi_n\to\, 0}\sum_{i=1}^n\Big|W_{t^n_i}-W_{t^n_{i-1}}\Big|\,\Big|N_{t^n_i}-N_{t^n_{i-1}}\Big|\\
&\le\lim_{\scriptstyle n\to\infty\atop\scriptstyle\Pi_n\to\, 0}\Bigg\{\underbrace{\max_{i=0,\dots,n}\Big|W_{t^n_i}-W_{t^n_{i-1}}\Big|}_{\textstyle\to 0}\cdot\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^nN_{t^n_i}-N_{t^n_{i-1}}}_{\textstyle N_t}\Bigg\}=0\,.
\end{align}

Edit: Your end result is correct but you could do a lot to improve the notation. I avoid physics notation such as
$$
dX_t*dX_t
$$
(not only because of that awful $*$) and prefer to calculate
quadratic variations in integral form. The relations
$$
[W]_t=t\,,\quad [N]_t=N_t\,,\quad [W,N]_t=0
$$ then lead to
$$
[X]_t =  \int_{0}^{t} \color{red}{s\,ds} + N_t=\frac{t^2}{2}+N_t\,.
$$
From there you can go to its differential form
$$
d[X]_t=t\,dt+dN_t
$$
if you want.

Comment: thank you, i can see why that holds now.
is my attempt correct in the solution above?